# How to call C/C++ asynchronous callback (in DLL) from JAVA

Tags: java, c, dll, asynccallback

I'd like to monitor Informatica ETL Workflows from custom Java program, via informatica Development Platform (LMapi), v9.1

I already have got C program, it works fine, but it would be great port to Java.

We get a lot of C DLLs, with asynchronous functions e.g.: JavaLMApi.dll, INFA_LMMonitorServerA (with detailed event-log possibilities)

In header we can see:

PMLM_API_EXTSPEC INFA_API_STATUS

INFA_LMMonitorServerA
( 
  INFA_UINT32 connectionId,
  struct INFA_LMAPI_MONITOR_SERVER_REQUEST_PARAMS *request,
  void *clientContext,
  INFA_UINT32 *requestId
);

There is no any documentation for this problem, only with this information should I use for soulution.

The question is: how to call/use INFA_LMMonitorServerA in Java? (Dll-load with JNA/JNI is not problem, only the callback).

```
static INFA_UINT32 nConnectionId = 0;

/* C-"skeleton": */
void GetSrvDetailcallback(struct INFA_API_REPLY_CONTEXT* GetSrvDetailReplyCtxt)
{
    INFA_API_STATUS apiRet;
    struct INFA_LMAPI_SERVER_DETAILS *serverDetails = NULL;
    char *serverStatus = NULL;

    /* Check if the return status is Acknowledgement */
    if (GetSrvDetailReplyCtxt->returnStatus == INFA_REQUEST_ACKNOWLEDGED)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "\nINFA REQUEST ACKNOWLEDGED \n\n",NULL);
        return;
    }

    apiRet = INFA_LMGetServerDetailsResults(GetSrvDetailReplyCtxt, &serverDetails);
    /* Check the return code if if is an error */
    if (INFA_SUCCESS != apiRet)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: INFA_LMGetServerDetailsResults returns %d\n", apiRet);
        return;
    }

    printResults(serverDetails);
}

static void myServer()
{
    struct INFA_LMAPI_CONNECT_SERVER_REQUEST_PARAMS_EX connectParamsex;
    INFA_API_STATUS apiRet;
    struct INFA_LMAPI_LOGIN_REQUEST_PARAMS loginparams;

    apiRet = INFA_LMLogin(nConnectionId, &loginparams, NULL);
    if (INFA_SUCCESS != apiRet)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: INFA_LMLogin returns %d\n", apiRet);
        return;
    }

    struct INFA_LMAPI_MONITOR_SERVER_REQUEST_PARAMS strMonitorRequestParams;
    //Only Running Tasks
    strMonitorRequestParams.monitorMode = INFA_LMAPI_MONITOR_RUNNING;
    strMonitorRequestParams.continuous = INFA_TRUE;

    /* Get Server Details */
    INFA_UINT32 GetSrvDetailsrequestId = 0;
    /* Register a callback function. */
    INFA_LMRegisterCallback(INFA_LMAPI_MONITOR_SERVER, &GetSrvDetailcallback);
    apiRet = INFA_LMMonitorServerA(nConnectionId, &strMonitorRequestParams, NULL, &GetSrvDetailsrequestId);
    if (INFA_SUCCESS != apiRet && INFA_REQUEST_PENDING != apiRet)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: INFA_LMMonitorServerA returns %d\n", apiRet);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could check out [JavaCPP - Creating Callbacks Functions](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#creating-callback-functions) for that. It would save you a lot of trouble.